# Android ArrayIndexOutofBounds Error

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

After some time trying to debug code, I haven't been able to figure out why this error is occurring.

My main `Activity` has a dialog box that allows for selection of items.
This is the code for it. mSelectedItems is a static `ArrayList` in the Main class.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                    mSelectedItems.add(which);
                }
                else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                    // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it 
                    mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                }

            }
        })

        // Set the action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                Data d = new Data();
                d.setSelectedPlayers(mSelectedItems);
                d.run();

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //CODE TO JUST CLOSE DIALOGBOX

            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
```

Now within this dialog, for the "Ok button" - I try to call a method from another class that does some calculations for the items selected on the dialogbox. I do this by setting the mSelectedItems arrayList in my main activity to the arrayList field in the other class (calling it Data class for now). Here's a chunk of relevant code for it:

```
private ArrayList<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Messi", "Ronaldo", "Turan", "Drogba","Kuyt"));

private int[] playerRatings =  {87, 78, 66, 69, 86};

    private ArrayList selectedPlayers;

        public void setSelectedPlayers(ArrayList mSelectedItems) {
            this.selectedPlayers = mSelectedItems;
        }

        public int run() {
            int totalScore = 0;
            for(Object player: selectedPlayers) {

                int index = playerNames.indexOf(player);
                int rating = playerRatings[index];
                int[] playersActionSet = actionMatrix[index];
```

Debugging tells me that the out of bounds error is the int index line. This code chunk needs to iterate over selectedPlayers (which will be assigned to mSelectedPlayers from the dialogbox in the other class) and find the index of each user selected item and then do calculations (calculations code not included here).

Can someone please explain why this error is happening? It seems like index is being assigned -1 everytime, but that happens only when a list is empty and you try to find indexOf of an item in it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you actually have two problems in your code:

Your first issue is in this line:

```
for(int i =0; i<=selectedPlayers.size(); i++) {
```

Change the <= to <, so that this line reads as follows:

```
for(int i =0; i<selectedPlayers.size(); i++) {
```

Index starts at 0 while size() starts at 1.

Moreover, change this line:

```
 int index = playerNames.indexOf(i);
```

to

```
 int index = playerNames.indexOf(selectedPlayers.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`for(int i =0; i<=selectedPlayers.size(); i++)` to

`if(selectedPlayers.size()!=0){
for(int i =0; i<=selectedPlayers.size()-1; i++) {}}`

Comment: This still gives the error. The problem is that selectdPlayers list IS empty. But I receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Change it with:

```
for(int i =0; i<selectedPlayers.size(); i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int index = playerNames.indexOf(i);
```

is giving -1 as `index` , because you are searching for an int `i` in an `ArrayList<String>`.

Now when you call:

```
int rating = playerRatings[index];
```

Here index is -1, and any array will give out Of bounds` error if you try to access a negative index.

So change:

```
int index = playerNames.indexOf(i);
```

to:

```
int index = playerNames.indexOf(selectedPlayers.get(i));
assert index >= 0 : "selected players must exist";
```

Comment: I changed the for loop to for(Object i : selectedPlayers) and int index = playerNames.indexOf(player). 
But I still get the same error. the index returned is -1 which means the selectedPlayers list is empty. I don't know why because I do select players manually on my phone in the debugger mode, and it stops on the int index line still for ArrayOutOfBound exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the maximum index of your list and I think you should update your for loop to be:

```
for(int i=0; i<selectedPlayers.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) the `indexOf(object)` method returns -1 if the list does not contain this element.
according to your code u are storing integers in `mSelectedItems` and passing its element to `indexOf()` method to a `ArrayList` which is holding String .. so there is a huge mismatch .

try this :-

```
private ArrayList<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Messi", "Ronaldo", "Turan", "Drogba","Kuyt"));

private int[] playerRatings =  {87, 78, 66, 69, 86};

    private ArrayList selectedPlayers;

        public void setSelectedPlayers(ArrayList mSelectedItems) {
            this.selectedPlayers = mSelectedItems;
        }

        public int run() {
            int totalScore = 0;
            for(Object player: selectedPlayers) {

                int index = (Integer)player; //casting to Integer .....this should work 
                int rating = playerRatings[index];
                int[] playersActionSet = actionMatrix[index];
```

reply if this fails